# Custom post types and 'new WP_Query'

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, categories

I have custom post type 'Partnerzy' already set. While adding new 'Partner', you select a category (kredyty, leasingi, etc.). And having that, I need to show them on a page, like this:
[image]

I figured out that all I need to do is take all 'Partnerzy' posts, group them by category and finally show them on the site.

My code looks like this:

```
$catArgs = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

  ); 

 $categoryList = get_categories( $catArgs );

  echo 'Sum: '.count($categoryList);

for ($i=0; $i < count($categoryList); $i++) {

  echo '<br>Number of loop: ' . $i;
  echo '<br>Category name: ' . $categoryList[$i]->name;

  $the_query_partnerzy = new WP_Query( array( post_type=>'Partnerzy', category_name=>$categoryList[$i]->name ) );

  echo count($the_query_partnerzy);

  if ($the_query_partnerzy->have_posts()) {

    echo 'I got it!';
    echo '<div class="post-list container">';
    echo '<p class="post-title">'. $categoryList[$i]->name .'</p>';

    while ($the_query_partnerzy->have_posts()) {

      $the_query_partnerzy->the_post();

      echo the_post_thumbnail();

    } // while

    echo '</div>';

  } // query partnerzy

} // for
```

Since I have few categories, I came with an idea to wrap it in a FOR loop. That works as far as this line:

```
    if ($the_query_partnerzy->have_posts())
```

And what is more interesting.. This line:

```
echo count($the_query_partnerzy);
```

really is counting elements in this query, but shows only 1 (weird). And having that, I'm not able to move further than this.

I would appreciate any kind or any form of help.

Comment: This is one of those annoying terminology mix-ups in WordPress - the `category_name` argument of `WP_Query` should actually be `$categoryList[$i]->slug` from `get_categories` results.

Comment: @Milo nope, it doesn't make any difference

Comment: did you fix the missing quotes around your argument names? do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? it's likely you have multiple issues that all need to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't know what problem you are trying to solve. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with this code, but:

> `echo count($the_query_partnerzy);`
>
> really is counting elements in this query, but shows only 1 (weird).
>   And having that, I'm not able to move further than this.

No, its not. `WP_Query` returns an object and [`count` doesn't work on Objects, mostly.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1314745)

The actual query results are in `$the_query_partnerzy->posts` so `count($the_query_partnerzy)` would give you what you want, but the `WP_Query` object already provides that data for you. Use `$the_query_partnerzy->found_posts` instead.

I cleaned up your code a bit, and this does work using the 'post' post type (so I could run the code and test it):

```
$catArgs = array(
  'type'                     => 'post',
  'child_of'                 => 0,
  'parent'                   => '',
  'orderby'                  => 'name',
  'order'                    => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty'               => 1,
  'hierarchical'             => 1,
  'exclude'                  => '',
  'include'                  => '',
  'number'                   => '',
  'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
  'pad_counts'               => false 
); 

$categoryList = get_categories( $catArgs );

echo 'Sum: '.count($categoryList);

$i = 0;// debugging ?
for ($categoryList as $catl) {
  echo '<br>Number of loop: ' . $i; // debugging ?
  echo '<br>Category name: ' . $catl->name;
  $the_query_partnerzy = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
      'post_type' =>'post', 
      'category_name' => $catl->name 
    ) 
  );
  echo $the_query_partnerzy->found_posts; // debugging ?
  if ($the_query_partnerzy->have_posts()) {
    echo 'I got it!'; // debugging ?
    echo '<div class="post-list container">';
    echo '<p class="post-title">'. $catl->name .'</p>';
    while ($the_query_partnerzy->have_posts()) {
      $the_query_partnerzy->the_post();
      echo the_post_thumbnail();
    } // while
    echo '</div>';
  } // query partnerzy
  $i++; // debugging ?
}
```

A few notes:

1. The lines marked `// debugging ?` most certainly should be removed.
2. The type of `for` loop you are using, while valid, is rarely
   necessary in PHP. There is a much more convenient `foreach`, and
   that `for` loop was causing some errors as (for reasons I have not
   investigated) the array given back by `get_categories()` started
   with `1` and not `0`. With `foreach` you don't have to worry about
   that.
3. You were missing quotes in your query arguments. That is, this:

   ```
     $the_query_partnerzy = new WP_Query( 
       array( 
         post_type => 'post', 
         category_name => $catl->name 
       ) 
     );
   ```

   Instead of this:

   ```
     $the_query_partnerzy = new WP_Query( 
       array( 
         'post_type' => 'post', 
         'category_name' => $catl->name 
       ) 
     );
   ```

   While that should have worked it was spitting out warning like
   crazy.
4. You are pulling categories from the `post` post type, but later are
   trying to pull posts from a different post type having those
   categories. Are you sure that the categories are registered for both
   post types and that there are in fact posts that fit that logic?

That said, the code is good and works for me.

Comment: I will try to explain.
1. get categories
2. for every category, show posts in given category

My problem is, that I can't show any posts on screen with my loop.

Comment: Unfortunately WP_Query doesn't have any posts in it, even though I created couple of them. Code doesn't go inside this: `if ($the_query_partnerzy->have_posts())`

Comment: Then your arguments are wrong. Possibly the capitalization of `Partnerzy`. I am not sure if case is critical or if post types can even be created with caps at all. I haven't looked into that. @Mentozz : I made another edit.

Comment: capitalization might not be a thing here, I tried to change it, still nothing

Comment: get_posts() returns 0

Comment: `get_posts()` appears nowhere in that code. Sorry, @Mentozz, you are going to have to do more debugging with this and find out exactly where things fail. I can only guess so much.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to you guys, I've figured out the answer.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($categoryList as $thisCategory) {

  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'partnerzy' ) );

  if ($query->have_posts()) {

    echo '<div class="post-list container">';
    echo '<p class="post-partners-title">'. $thisCategory->name .'</p>';
    echo '<div class="row">';

    while ($query->have_posts()) {

      if (in_category($thisCategory->slug, $query->the_post())) {

        echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 partner-item">';
        echo '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
        echo the_post_thumbnail();
        echo the_title('<span>', '</span>');
        echo '</div></div>';

      }

    } // while

    echo '</div></div>';

  } else {

    echo '<br>nope<br><br>';

  } // query partnerzy

  wp_reset_postdata();

} // foreach
```

Thanks for your time. Cheers